# 3rd Party API call in MEAN

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack

I am learning MEAN stack and doing a POC to connect Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with MEAN. To connect FCM (or any other 3rd party API) to MEAN, can we connect to Angular directly or do we have to connect through Express. Which is the best practice to follow.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So the answer would be yes and yes :). it totally depends on what you would like to archive. I personally would always prefer the express way, since you do not have to include all firebase libraries in the frontend. The other advantage is, that you don´t need to care about authentication on client-side (yes, on server-side / express you will have to, but here you will be the "firebase-admin"). If you only want to use it for the web, you can also consider sockets... like with your own message interface aso...

Comment: Thank you. So i can prefer the express way of connecting to FCM or any 3rd party API's.